# (the) public and (the) private

Tags: definite-article

I am unsure about the use of the definite article in the following two cases:

- The division between the public and the private is not very clear.
- The division between public and private space is not very clear. (in this case without the)

Thank you very much for your answers!

Comment: Did you mean to omit "space" from the first example?

Comment: What is the context? What space are you talking about?

Comment: By the way, we would need [more details](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) in order to answer this question properly. Regardless, I think it is going to come down to the usual rules regarding the definite article, which have been discussed [many times on ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=when+to+use+definite+article).

Comment: The articles are optional in both cases (changing *public* and *private* from nouns into adjectives modifying *space* doesn't significantly affect things). If the speaker wishes to give the impression that *the public [world]* and *the private [world]* are two well-known realms, the case for the definite article is stronger (but of course it's *weakened* by a context where the speaker is claiming that we don't even know them well enough to make a clear distinction between them! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think that public-versus-private is a sufficiently familiar contrast to license *the public* and *the private* as referable categories in the discourse; and even if it weren't, the context (*division between*) provides adequate categorization. In any case, I imagine that the underlying sense is that *The division between the public and the private is not by any means so clear **as it is commonly taken to be.***

Comment: @StoneyB: Sufficiently familiar? I should coco! Google Books thinks it has over 10,000 written instances of [**the distinction between the public and the private**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+distinction+between+the+public+and+the+private%22). A few add an explicit noun *(space, world, domain, sphere, etc.)*, but most don't. I suppose that in the absence of such a noun we might just be talking about the "contextless" semantic distinction between two adjectives, but that wouldn't usually be the case.

Comment: @FumbleFingers is correct in this case. There are nuances, but in the main he has the sense of it.

Comment: The raw and the cooked.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is a confusing issue.

The primary use of the definite article is to distinguish a particular instance  (of which the reader already knows or will come to know) from the generic type. For example "the house" vs "a house."

The terms **public** and **private** can be used as adjectives. Then preceding them by "the" is not appropriate. For example "public services" and "private property".

**The public** can be used as a noun, in which case it is always preceded by "the" and might also have an adjective. For example : "the general public."

Those are the simple cases.

More ambiguously, **the public** and **the private** can be used (with the definite article) to refer to abstract ideas or mutually exclusive "realms" in the political/economic arena. However, as FumbleFingers points out, in this case the meaning is much the same if we use **public** and **private** without "the" as adjectives. The difference - if there is one - is subtle.

Your examples demonstrate the abstract use, and work both ways with substantially the same meaning. The following possibilities are all correct  (I have taken the liberty of changing "division") :

- The distinction between the public and the private is not very clear.
- The distinction between (what is) public and (what is) private is not very clear.
- The distinction between public (property) and private (property) is not very clear.
- The distinction between the public (sector) and the private (sector) is not very clear.

The comments by FumbleFingers are worth repeating :

> The [definite] article is optional in both cases : changing public and private from nouns into adjectives modifying "space" doesn't significantly affect things.
>
> If the speaker wishes to give the impression that the public [world] and the private [world] are two well-known realms, the case for the definite article is stronger - but of course it's weakened by a context where the speaker is claiming that we don't even know them well enough to make a clear distinction between them!